# CSS media query overwriting the style of the page, even in lower resolutions

Tags: css, media-queries

There is something strange going on with a page that I'm working. I want a certain style when a device has a lower resolution than 600px of width, and another when the screen is bigger. The problem is that the page shows me the media query style even when the resolution is lower. Any ideas as of why this can happen? I don't think I'm doing anything wrong

```
#logo{
    width: 605px;
    height: 243px;
    background-image: url(images/move_filled_sm_X1.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
}
#bars{
    width: 87px;
    height: 93px;
    margin-top: 90px;
    background-image: url(images/bars-solid.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
    #logo{
        width: 409px;
        height: 164px;
    }
    #bars{
        width: 60px;
        height: 64px;
        margin-top: 67px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you wrote the code it will render the part above the media query for screens smaller than 600px in width. But for screens that have a width of 600px or more will ALSO apply the styles inside the media query:

EXAMPLE what will be used fo 600px and above screen:

```
#logo{
    //width: 605px;
    //height: 243px;
    background-image: url(images/move_filled_sm_X1.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    // Overwritten due to media query
    width: 409px;
    height: 164px;
}
#bars{
    //width: 87px;
    //height: 93px;
    //margin-top: 90px;
    background-image: url(images/bars-solid.svg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    // Overwritten due to media query
    width: 60px;
    height: 64px;
    margin-top: 67px;
}
```

If you don't want this you could wrap the first thing in a media query as well.

Did you use this? `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Comment: Thak you so much, it seems that I was missing the meta tag in my html. What I find very odd is that in the past I've never used it, but the queries that I implemented had worked without giving me so much trouble.

Comment: @Nicho it could be due to the main html file implementing this already (if you use a [SPA](https://medium.com/@NeotericEU/single-page-application-vs-multiple-page-application-2591588efe58)) or the css file having it declared in a [@viewport](https://benfrain.com/understanding-the-viewport-meta-tag-and-css-viewport/#h-H2_7)